# What is Regal OpenGL?

Tags: c++, c, opengl, opengl-es

I just surfing on Github and find a recent project called regal opengl,
https://github.com/p3/regal

I've understand this is a technology to write opengl code for all plateforms ?

Tutorials or explanations are available on this framework?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Regal OpenGL can be used to run any version of OpenGL (1.x 2.x 3.x ) on any platform.

You need not change your current OpenGL code. Instead of linking with the OpenGL lib you have, link it against Regal OpenGL. Use #include . Link with regal32.dll (windows), libRegal.so (Linux) or libRegal.dylib.

It isnt stable as yet. Give it time before you use it for commercial projects.